# Developing an Discord Bot, something wrong with code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to make an Discord bot with Node.JS and Discord.JS. The point of the bot is that when an user writes !steve the bot will move the user steve from my discord server to the AFK chat if he is in an voice chat.
Here's my code, but it doesn't work! Can someone help me fix this?

I want the bot to move the user Steve in the discord server to the voice chat channel AFK when a user types !steve in the chat.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const prefix = "!"

    client.on('ready', () => {
      console.log(`Bot launched. Bot ${client.user.tag} is successfully activated!`);
    client.user.setStatus("online");
    client.user.setGame('Gay Porn ', 'https://www.twitch.tv/food');

    });
    client.on('message', msg => {
      if (msg.content === prefix + 'steve') {
        msg.reply('Have fun in the AFK chat steve!!')
    var user = message.guild.members.find("185401917520871424", USERID_SOUL);
            await member.setVoiceChannel("306166618835255297");
      }
    })

    client.login('private');
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

When you were making the variable `user`, you should probably change message to msg.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late but `await` only works with `async`.